# Comment form above comments?

Tags: 6, forms, comments

Is there a simple way to move the comment form above the comments in Drupal 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Comment form above comments](http://drupal.org/project/comment_form_above_comments) module which adds option to place comment form above the comments thread.

Comment: Haha, what an aptly named module.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple thing to do in your theme so if you don't want to install another module just to do it you can override the [comment-wrapper.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment-wrapper.tpl.php/7) template file in your theme.

Just copy that file to your theme from the comment module (or if your theme is a sub-theme you there might be one in your base theme, in which case use that one - in this case the example coe below may not exactly match your base theme's code).

Then move this part:

```
<?php if ($content['comment_form']): ?>
  <h2 class="title comment-form"><?php print t('Add new comment'); ?></h2>
  <?php print render($content['comment_form']); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

So it is where you want it.
In this case probably just above the line:

```
<?php print render($content['comments']); ?>
```

You can do this for a specific node type by renaming the file to comment-wrapper--node-NODETYPE.tpl.php, where NODETYPE is replaced with the machine name of your content type (with any underscores changed to dashes).

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way I found was with CSS 
Note: I only want to do this with a specific Content type with the class ".node-chat-with-a-character" the height/padding of 200px was specific to my solution, and was a number I arrived at after removing a lot of extraneous things from the comment form.

```
/*put comment submit above comments*/
```

.node-chat-with-a-character #comments {
   position: relative; 
   padding-top: 200px;
}

.node-chat-with-a-character #comments .comment-form{
   position: absolute;
   height: 200px;
   top: 0px;
}

Answer (score -1):

Put this in a block; it is the best and easiest method.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('.box').prependTo('#comments');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: How is this the best method?  You've got code in a block for starters - this is the start of a downward spiral to a totally unmanageable site.